Perl: inline variable substitution not working
Below is the perl script
my $var="
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
da:be:66:35:0e:47:0f:60:f1:70:a4:43:ff:39:da:65.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/PCS/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending key in /home/PCS/.ssh/known_hosts:144
Password authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Keyboard-interactive authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Filesystem                 1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-lscratch 7288301568 6079377352 1208924216  84% /scratch
";

$var =~ s/.+Filesystem/Filesystem/g;
print "$var\n";

What it is printing is ($var value):
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
da:be:66:35:0e:47:0f:60:f1:70:a4:43:ff:39:da:65.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/PCS/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending key in /home/PCS/.ssh/known_hosts:144
Password authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Keyboard-interactive authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Filesystem22                 1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-lscratch 7288301568 6079377352 1208924216  84% /scratch

It seems substitution is not working.
As per my knowledge, $var should have print the below, but it is not. How can it be done? What's wrong in this substitution?
Filesystem                 1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-lscratch 7288301568 6079377352 1208924216  84% /scratch


So you expect the first 13 lines of output to NOT occur? Why?

That's the need of my code. I am getting $var after some processing which can't be controlled, and i need to process it.

@AskQuestionsP Well, did you try one of ikegami's suggestions?

@TedLyngmo, yes it worked

. matches any character other than a LF. But you want to match any character incl LF. You use /s to do that.
s/.*Filesystem/Filesystem/sg

Clarify that Filesystem appears at the start of a line (to avoid problems with paths that contain Filesystem):
s/.*^Filesystem/Filesystem/msg

Prevent needless backtracking on failed match:
s/\A.*^Filesystem/Filesystem/msg

Remove repetition:
s/\A.*^(?=Filesystem)//msg


It worked, thanks! But for my knowledge, can you explain what /s and /m do?

/s changes what . matches as I described. /m changes what ^ and $ match. See perlre
